# export all database data to xml format with SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, database

I have .bak format file with database from another company. After a long time of configuration SQL Server I have access to this data but Is there any way to export all database to XML format? Is there easiest way than export every table by typing:

```
SELECT * from MLS.dbo.Offers

FOR XML AUTO
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an exact answer but following SQL will help you to list down all the schema and table names. And you can build a dynamic SQL thing around this result set to achieve what you want.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       DB_NAME() AS [Database],
       SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID) AS [Schema],
       Name AS [Table]
FROM sys.tables
ORDER BY 1,2;
```